# how to parse custom error revert in web3js

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, ethers.js

hey so web3js doesn't give me what custom error was thrown.

say i have the following code

```
contract Dummy {
    error MY_ERROR();

    function foo() external pure {
        revert MY_ERROR();
    }
}
```

on calling `foo()` with web3, it just gives the following error response

```js
{
  "originalError": {
    "code": 3,
    "data": "0x888f5130",
    "message": "execution reverted"
  }
}
```

this is supported in ethersjs, so i'm guessing there must also be a way in web3js, help appreciated!

Comment: I also want to know the answer to this

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this article
https://blog.emn178.cc/en/post/using-web3-js-to-parse-custom-error/

Define some methods

```js
import { Eip838ExecutionError } from 'web3';
import { decodeContractErrorData } from 'web3-eth-abi';

function parseInnerError(e, contract) {
  if (e?.innerError?.errorSignature) {
    return e.innerError;
  }

  if (!e.innerError) {
    if (e?.data?.data.startsWith('0x')) {
      e.innerError = new Eip838ExecutionError(e.data);
    }
  }
  if (e?.innerError?.data?.startsWith('0x')) {
    decodeContractErrorData(contract._errorsInterface, e.innerError);
  }
  return e.innerError;
}

const KEYS = ['to', 'from', 'nonce', 'gas', 'gasPrice', 'maxPriorityFeePerGas', 'maxFeePerGas', 'data', 'value', 'chainId', 'type', 'accessList'];
async function parseTxError(txHash, web3, contract) {
  const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
  const request = { };
  KEYS.forEach((key) => {
    request[key] = tx[key];
  });
  if (request.gasPrice) {
    delete request.maxPriorityFeePerGas;
    delete request.maxFeePerGas;
  }
  try {
    await web3.eth.call(request, tx.blockNumber);
    return null;
  } catch (e) {
    return parseInnerError(e, contract);
  }
}
```

And in your case, you can try

```js
try {
  await dummy.methods.foo({ from });
} catch (e) {
  const innerError = parseInnerError(e, dummy);
}
```

Comment: please expand. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587